# Use something like this "input[class~="valid" && type="checkbox"]?

Tags: css, expression

How can I achieve this  `input[class~="valid" && type="checkbox"]` ? 
Can I use expressions(e.g. `&&,|`) in CSS(may be in LESS) ?

Or is this the only way ?

```
input[class~="valid"],input[type="checkbox"] { ...}
```

or

```
input.valid[type="checkbox"]
```

Thanks

Comment: it is `input[class~="valid"][type="checkbox"]`

Comment: The question title reflects just part of the question, as the question body asks about “or” too (|).

Answer (score 3):

You need to use

```
input[type="checkbox"][class~="valid"] { ...}
```

Your attempt means: all `valid` and all checkboxes.

Comment: All checkboxes having .valid constraint

Answer (score 2):

Multiple attribute selectors can be added by defining them after each other:

```
input[class~="valid"][type="checkbox"]
{
}
```